# Can I access the binding that contains all the declared variables for current class/method in Scala?

Tags: scala, binding

Is there a way to get a binding containing all the declared variables, using Scala 2.9? I would like to pass all of them along to the ILoop interpreter.

Comment: Do you mean "all variables in scope", or "all field values of the current instance", or what?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, both, if possible.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a reasonable question---such a thing might be possible in other languages. But in Scala the answer is no, this is compile time information that cannot be reified as a run-time object.

Comment: Despite the accepted answer, I'm inclined to think this is possible, so long as you're targeting just Hotspot and its debugging APIs, and you can stomach the hacks - I just don't know how to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Sorry.